# Showing that invertibility implies coercivity

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, bilinear-form, coercive

I'm trying to proof the following:

*Let $f$ be a continous sesquilinear form on a Hilbertspace $H$ and let $A: H \to H$ be its dedicated Operator such that
$$f(u,v) = \langle u, Av \rangle_H \;\;\; \forall u,v \in H.$$
If $A$ is invertible, then $f$ is coercive, i.e. $\exists C > 0: |f(x,x)| \geq C ||x||^2 \; \forall x \in H$.*

My attempt: The invertibility of $A$ gives me that $\exists c > 0: ||Ax|| \geq c ||x|| \; \forall x \in H$.

How do I put this in relation to $|f(x,x)| = |\langle x, Ax \rangle|$ or how do I find a lower bound for this term in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. What is $T$?  Is $T = A$? In that case the statement is false. Take e.g. $H = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T$ to be a rotation by 90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I corrected it. You are right.

Comment: I cannot see the correction. What is $T$?

Comment: You probably want to assume some self-adjointness.

Comment: It was $T = A$, I forgot to replace one of the $T$'s. We got this statement as an exercise to proof. We are starting with a continous sesquilinear form $f$ and get $A$ from it, so I don't think we can demand self-adjointness since $A$ is unique for a given $f$.

Comment: Try this with the sesquilinear form $f(u,v) = \bar u_1 v_2 - \bar u_2 v_1$, for $u, v \in H = \mathbb{C}^2$. Or even simpler try $f(u,v) = -\bar u_1 v_1 - \bar u_2 v_2$. What is $A$? Is $A$ invertible? Is the form $f$ coercive? There is your counterexample.